# SplunkMint uploading dSym

Tags: xcode, splunk

I am receiving this error every time I try to run the following script (SplunkMint script to upload the dsym file automatically in order to symbolicate):

```
SCRIPT=`/usr/bin/find "${SRCROOT}" -name splunkmint_postbuild_dsym_upload_script.sh | head -n 1`

/bin/bash "${SCRIPT}" "API_KEY" "API_TOKEN"
```

I put my API_KEY and API_TOKEN but they are hidden for security reasons.

```
Splunk Mint: Archiving "appName" to "/tmp/splunk-mint-dsyms/appName.zip"
  adding: appName (deflated 72%)
Splunk Mint: ERROR "400" while uploading "/tmp/splunk-mint-dsyms/appName.zip"
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 252
```

I don't know what can cause this issue, I just used other previous versions that I didn't had the issue and now I do.

I am using **Swift 4** and **Xcode 9.2**,
Thanks.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Still without solution, if you found some thing please I would love you share it with me. Thanks.

Comment: I too facing same issue since yesterday. any help ?

Comment: Still without solution..

Comment: @Eironeia i just removed the run script and uploaded the DSYM file manually. It worked for me. Just give it a try.

Comment: I am just doing that for now, but I think if they offer the automatic way it should work somehow. Let's see on the next update.

Comment: Please refer to this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362270/splunkmint-uploading-dsym