# Splunk MINT shell script Issue: Issue occurs when I attempt to archive an application in Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, xcode, splunk, xcode9.3

I have integrated Splunk MINT SDK with IOS app. Here is the issue details:

I am able to run the app in Simulator, but not in Device. While archiving I got below error.

```
Splunk Mint: Archiving "Appointment-Plus" to "/tmp/splunk-mint-dsyms/Appointment-Plus.zip"

adding: Appointment-Plus (deflated 68%)

Splunk Mint: ERROR "400" while uploading "/tmp/splunk-mint-dsyms/Appointment-Plus.zip"

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 252
```

Any help?

Comment: Please refer to this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362270/splunkmint-uploading-dsym

Answer (score -1):

I just removed the Splunk MINT shell script and archive the app, Unit tested in TestFlight and eventually submitted to AppStore. working good and tracking events and transactions successfully. No Issues, Thanks!